# Only load files with date range from command line pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have file names with the date, I would like to fetch range of files from directory and put them into pandas dataframe, DO NOT WANT TO LOAD ALL OF THE FILES

```
020-03-01.csv   2020-03-23.csv  2020-04-14.csv  2020-05-06.csv
2020-03-02.csv  2020-03-24.csv  2020-04-15.csv  2020-05-07.csv
2020-03-03.csv  2020-03-25.csv  2020-04-16.csv  2020-05-08.csv
2020-03-04.csv  2020-03-26.csv  2020-04-17.csv  2020-05-10.csv
2020-03-05.csv  2020-03-27.csv  2020-04-19.csv  2020-05-11.csv
2020-03-06.csv  2020-03-29.csv  2020-04-20.csv  2020-05-12.csv
2020-03-08.csv  2020-03-30.csv  2020-04-21.csv  2020-05-13.csv
2020-03-09.csv  2020-03-31.csv  2020-04-22.csv  2020-05-14.csv
2020-03-10.csv  2020-04-01.csv  2020-04-23.csv  2020-05-15.csv
2020-03-11.csv
```

I would like to fetch only file which are in range given as start date and end date and take the start date as `sys.argv[1]` and end date `sys.argv[2]`
i.e nameofthescript `2020-03-01 2020-03-20`

Comment: Please take a look at the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section of the documentation and provide a minimum, reproducible, example of your code and what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have the script on the same directory as your CSV files (and all the CSV files have the same format `XXXX-MM-DD.csv` where the dates are monotonically increasing) and that you had made the script executable with (`chmod +x script.py`) the following `script.py` should work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import sys
import pandas as pd

filepath = "/path/to/csvfiles/" #[TODO] change to the path where the csv files are located.

try:
    first_file = sys.argv[1]
    second_file = sys.argv[2]
except:
    print("An error occurred. Enter two file names separated by a space in the format of YYYY-MM-D1 YYYY-MM-D2")
    sys.exit(1)

csv_files = [csv_file for csv_file in os.listdir(filepath) if csv_file.endswith('.csv')]
ordered_files = sorted(csv_files)

try:
    index_first_file = ordered_files.index(first_file)
    index_second_file = ordered_files.index(second_file)
except:
     print("One of the csv files was not found in the current directory.")
     sys.exit(1)

df_list = [pd.read_csv(ordered_files[i]) for i in range(index_first_file, index_second_file+1)]

print(df_list)
```

In order to use it simply run e.g. `./script.py 2020-03-01.csv 2020-03-02.csv`

Comment: This works great Thank you so much, what do I have to do if I do not want to run the script from the directory rather define directory path and have run from the path,so I can run from anywhere.                                 i.e /home/foo/bar/*/boo/

Comment: Simply make sure to add the absolute path on the `filepath` variable for the `os.listdir()` command to properly find the location where your files are stored. More information about how to properly use the `os.listdir()` command on the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/os.html#os.listdir)

Comment: path = “/var/tmp/share/*/archives/“

filepath = glob.glob(os.path.join(path,r'*.csv'))

filepath2 = os.listdir(path)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/tmp/share/*/archives/'

Comment: I guess the ideal thing would be to put the script in a folder (e.g. home/username/scripts/) and put the csv files in a folder relative to that path (e.g. home/username/scripts/files) and use the relative filepath on the filepath variable (filepath = "./files/"). If that doesn't work get the full path as to where the csv files are located (In Linux use readlink -f 2020-03-01.csv) and change the filepath variable accordingly.